# how to solve size mismatch for this model?

Tags: pytorch

```
data_transforms = {
'train': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
'val': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.CenterCrop(256),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
```

batchsize=4

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=5, padding=1)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=5, padding=1)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256*6*6, 4096)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 4096)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4096, 2)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1)
    print(x.shape)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))  
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [4 x 373248], m2: [9216 x 4096] at C:/w/1/s/tmp_conda_3.8_075429/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1579852542185/work/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:290
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided debug information we can only tell that there is a size mismatch in one of the layers.

Looking at the error, it seems the error is in the first linear layer. You should change its size to 373248 instead of 256*6*6.

This should also be clear from the output of the print statement `print(x.shape)`.